# How to remove extra space of one line

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, overleaf

I am not much familiar with Latex, and I am struggling with one extra line that is left behind after the Project title, as shown in the figure after the Face Mask title.

How shall I get rid of it?

[image]

**This is code related to that section**

```
 \project
{Face Mask Detection and Social Distancing Application}{2017 - 2018}

{
                   \begin{itemize}
                   \item Scrapped images | Face Detection using ONNX Pre-trained model| Trained an Xception \& VGG16 | Compared Performance | yolov5 trained on Dataset from roboflow.ai | Data Augmentation using ImgAug
    \item Deployed FaceMasque package on pip
    \item Appreciated by HoD of College and planning to deploy on campus CCTV Cameras

                  \end{itemize}
                }
{YOLOv3 Object Detection , Deep Sort Object Tracking , SQL Database, Image Processing, Data Analysis}
```

**This is defined inside cls file**

```
\newenvironment{projects}{%
  \begin{longtable}{l}
}{%
  \end{longtable}
}

% Define the 'project' entry in the 'projects' environment
% Usage:
% \project
%   {<Project name>}{<dates>}
%   {<link1> <link2>}
%   {<Project description>}
%   {<techno1>,<techno2>}
\newcommand\project[5]{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(\linewidth) - 1.5em}
    \textbf{\textsc{#1}} \hfill \textsc{#2}\smallskip\\
    #3\\
    #4\smallskip\\
    \footnotesize{\foreach \n in {#5}{\cvtag{\n}}}\\
  \end{minipage}
  \\*
}
```

Moreover, if I do not explicitly put a new line after

```
{Face Mask Detection and Social Distancing Application}{2017 - 2018}
```

Then, I am getting error as **runaway argument**

```
errorRunaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@normal@list was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.26    
    
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

The complete cls file is present here
[CLS file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ie-afqpr-xcCiFRUgJ2pbE6O6nLYhmqu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: please post self contained complete MWE. Not fragments of Latex code. This makes it easier to copy and compile and try.

Comment: @Nasser I had updated and placed cls file

Comment: You missing two arguments if I read your code correctly `\project{}{}{}{}{}`.